# Rails JOIN model dependent destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, many-to-many, associations

Let's say, I have the following models:

```
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :targetings
  has_many :devices, :through => :targetings
  attr_accessible lalalala, :device_ids
end

class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :targetings
  has_many :campaigns, :through => :targetings
end

class Targetings < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :campaign
  belongs_to :targeting
  has_many :docs, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Doc < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :targeting
end
```

It is simple **Campaigns** - **Devices** many-to-many association with join model (**Targetings**). **Targeting** has many associated docs, which I want to be destroyed on targeting destroy.

On edit page there is a checkbox-set with name '**campaign[device_ids]**', which I use to choose devices for current campaign.

I have added `device_ids` to **Campaign**'s `attr_acessible`, and Rails were able to somehow manage association between **Campaigns** and **Devices**: it implicitly creates **Targeting** model.

However, when I delete association between Campaign and Device, Targeting model is destroyed, but Docs associated with that Targeting is not destroyed.

**Example:**

```
Devices: 
  id: 1
  title: A
  ----
  id: 2
  title: B

Campaigns:
  id: 1
  title: CA

Targetings:
  id: 1
  device_id: 1
  campaign_id: 1

Docs:
  id: 1
  content: lalala
  targeting_id: 1
```

That's the initial state. When I request:
`POST campaign/1/update`, with `device_ids = [2]` I will have

```
Targetings:
  id: 2
  device_id: 2
  campaign_id: 1
```

but still

```
Docs:
  id: 1
  content: lalala
  targeting_id: 1
```

So, Targetings[id=1] was deleted, but dependent Docs were not deleted.

Is it an expected behavior? Should I manually update associations? If so, what is the right way to do it?

**P.S.** Targeting should always be created implicitly.

Comment: I don't know that this will work, but have you tried `Campaign has_many :targetings, :dependent => :destroy`? I wonder whether join table records are by default `deleted` rather than `destroyed`, which would skip callbacks (like destroying further dependent records).

Comment: @gregates unfortunately, it had no effect: dependent docs are still untouched. Seems like, the reason is somewhere in rails targeting management. I will try redefine device_ids= method, and manually manage association.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like (*from official docs*)

> Automatic deletion of join models is direct, no destroy callbacks are
>   triggered.

Not an obvious decision at first glance - I think it was made so for performance reasons.
However, I was able to solve the problem above, by using `after_remove` hook on devices association:

```
has_many :devices, :through => :targetings, :before_remove => :destroy_targeting

def destroy_targeting(device)
    Targeting.where(campaign_id: id, device_id: device.id).destroy_all
end
```